# Nautilus crashed - Black desktop and can't access any folder

Tags: nautilus, trash

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
The other day I put some files in the trash (I work with photography, so I normally have to delete big files everyday) and my desktop crashed. It became black and files disappeared. I couldn't open any folder nor any document, folders are all freezed, and the trash seems empty (even though I can't get into it). Reboot did nothing. 
I started to read multiple forum posts, I tried to erase and reinstall nautilus, but anything worked. Only `sudo nautilus` gives me my desktop and folders functionality back, but only if I keep the terminal open with this command (and now I know it's not a recommended command, to).

From what I've understood, I need to get back the ownership of some files that are now in root's hands. 
I've tried these commands to do so, but terminal says that there's something missing after gvfs-metadata:

```
cd ~/.local/share

sudo chown $USER -R ./gvfs-metadata
```

Can somebody please help me find a solution?
Thanks!

Comment: Your chown command looks in the wrong order. Let's assume that your user name on ubuntu is "ottopiloto". Then the chown commande would be: "sudo chown -R ottopiloto:ottopiloto gvfs-metadata". Please note that you an check a file owner and access rights from terminal with "ls -l" command. It lists all folders and files in the current directory, their owner and access rights.

Comment: Thanks. No success. First command "sudo chown...." creates no response in the terminal and no changes. Just a new command line below. The second command "ls -I" opens a list of files and folders, but they are all owned by ottolapiloto (which is me)

Comment: Well at least it confirms that gvfs-metadata is not the one creating your problem :-(

Comment: One thing to try maybe: from your account, open a terminal and create a new user e.g. "sudo adduser ottolapiloto2" (More documentation here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AddUsersHowto#Command-line). Then disconnect from your account and connect with the new user account. Does it change anything?

Comment: Yes, it does! I can open folders with the new user. I would appreciate getting back mi original user, though, since I have a lot of files there :(

Comment: Great, we are getting closer :) For some reasons, it seems that your user account lost some permissions. The idea is then to move your files from ottolapiloto to ottolapiloto2, remove ottolapiloto and rename ottolapiloto2 to ottolapiloto. First, can you copy all the content from /home/ottolapiloto to /home/ottolapiloto2 ? The command should be "sudo cp -ri /home/ottolapiloto /home/ottolapiloto2" Terminal will prompt you for overwriting "Document", "Music"... i.e. all default directories. Say yes to them. Then try to disconnect and reconnect with ottolapiloto2 account. Are all your files there?

Comment: BTW you should be able to do it graphically too if you launch Nautilus with sudo :) So a simple copy-paste from your former home/ottolapiloto to the new one (/home/ottolapiloto2) will give you the same result!

Comment: Thanks! I tried it with the terminal but it stopped after 15 minutes because there's no space on the disk. My trash may be occupying a lot of it... but... new complication! I can't empty the trash! I've tried it manually and through  "sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/*"

Comment: Ok. You can also try to move the files directly instead of copy, that avoids space increase. But it sounds a bit more risky, that's why I didn't suggest it first.

Comment: Yes, I'm finally doing that. Thank you, I appreciate your dedication

Comment: Did it work as expected? Can you retrieve all your files within the new account?

Comment: Hi! I've copied the desktop files and the download files to the new user. I'm not sure if I should copy anything else? (I have my other files in a portable disk). Now I'm trying to change the admin to ottolapiloto2 and then delete ottolapiloto

Comment: Good. Indeed files on external drive are not to be moved. Usually you can copy all files from your personal folder i.e. ottolapiloto. This folder contains your documents, images and so on... but also your local settings such as preferences for your applications, your emails if you use an email client, your theme... to summarize, all things that you customized on your profile! I recommend to move all files, including hidden files, that are in /home/ottolapiloto.

Comment: Once you've confirmed that all your files are now in ottolapiloto2 and accessible with this account, you can rename older account e.g. "usermod --login ottolapiloto_old /home/ottolapiloto_old --move-home /home/ottolapiloto". Then disconnect and reconnect with ottolapiloto_old, open a terminal and rename the new user acount: "usermod --login ottolapiloto /home/ottolapiloto --move-home /home/ottolapiloto2". Last, disconnect, connect again with ottolapiloto, check again that you have all your files :-) and remove the old account: "sudo deluser ottolapiloto_old".

Comment: If everything is still fine, you can also remove ottolapiloto_folder: "sudo rm -r /home/ottolapiloto_old". I wait for your confirmation that all went as expected and I will write an answer that summarizes all the steps to facilitate future reference :)

Comment: Done! I have deleted ottolapiloto. Thank you very much for your time and knowledge!!! Do you want me to help in anything?

Comment: I'm really glad that it worked :-). Enjoy! I've summarized all the steps in the answer below - if you're fine with it, please accept it as the answer for other people's future reference. I just wonder what happened that made you loose access rights to your Gnome application :s I hope it will not happen anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we had a lot of exchanges in comment, here is the summary of the answers for readability and easier future reference.

In general, we more done a work around: we have created a new user and copied the files, rather than restoring the account affected by access rights loss.

Since you could still launch terminal in your session, you have created a new user:

```
sudo adduser ottolapiloto2
```

This new user had a fully working Gnome, which confirmed that the issue had to do with access rights for your original "ottolapiloto" account.

Then you moved the content of /home/ottolapiloto to /home/ottolapiloto2. If possible, I would have rather recommended to copy instead of moving to avoid risk of losing files, but your drive had no free space enough to allow duplication of your home directory. So in this case, it is good to backup files on an external drive if possible. You did this graphically with a Nautilus session with sudo rights. It could have been done with terminal too.

After confirming that this was indeed moving the files from your former account to the new one, you could rename the old account:

```
sudo usermod --login ottolapiloto_old /home/ottolapiloto_old --move-home /home/ottolapiloto
```

At this time, you had 2 user accounts: ottolapiloto_old (affected) and ottolapiloto2 (working fine) . So then you could disconnect and reconnect with ottolapiloto_old, open a terminal and rename the new user account:

```
sudo usermod --login ottolapiloto /home/ottolapiloto --move-home /home/ottolapiloto2
```

Here you had 2 user accounts: ottolapiloto_old (affected) and ottolapiloto. So last, you could disconnect again, connect back with ottolapiloto, check again that you had all your files :-) and remove the old affected account:

```
sudo deluser ottolapiloto_old
```

Enjoy!